# Implement SharePoint Search with Enterprise custom fields of Project server sites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, project-server

I have a project server enabled in my SharePoint 2013 farm. In which I have different project sites are created. All the sites have some additional `Enterprise custom fields`. Some fields are as below:

[image]

Now I want to search the same value of field `Projectleader` in SharePoint 2013 by just entering the keyword `xyz`.

I have found out that all this custom fields are stored in separate database but I am not sure how will crawl these data and display them as a result.

Does anyone have idea about solution?

Comment: If they are in a separate database and not available to the project team site crawl, you could use BCS to return the data to the crawler.